# WPF to crossplatform development, What's the most powerful cross platform UI framework?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, macos

So we built a WPF app, now for our next version we need a Mac version as well.

Mono obviously jumps to mind, but our app is fairly intensive for the UI.  Is there anything cross platform that is remotely close to what WPF gives you for styling your apps?

Granted the current app is C#, but if we need to go back to c++ for the sake of a clean UI that wouldn't be a problem. Is this a situation where you might eventually get back to writing two separate UIs in C++ one for cocoa and one for win32?

Comment: One option would be to migrate your back-end to C++, have wrappers for it in C# and leave your Windows UI in WPF, and use Cocoa for Macs

Comment: Your backend should be UI-agnostic *anyway*. It makes updating the UI a lot simpler when it is a layer on top of your business logic rather than mixed in with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the solution requiring the least effort, while still having a decent UI on Mac OS X, would be to use [Monobjc](http://www.monobjc.net/) or [MonoMac](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac). If you want to be lazy, you can always use GTK#. It comes by default with Mono and has the added benefit that it is also be compatible with Linux.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, it would be much preferable to have two UIs, one for windows, and the other for Mac using Objective-C/Cocoa.

There is no easy way to obtain a "native" user experience on the Mac without using ObjC/Cocoa. Programs not using Cocoa on the Mac can be spotted from far away.

Well, in the end, it also depends on your business objective and your value proposition.

Answer (score 2):

Use GTK+ or wxWidgets or Qt or any other cross platform libraries with c++.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an MVVM or MVC approach. The business logic written in C++, if necessary; wrapper classes in Managed C++ and the view completely independant of that. WPF already helps with that by splitting the view from the logic. Now for the mac part, i can't give a good UI Sdk for that. But seperating the business logic as much as possible from the UI makes it fairly easy to use what ever UI API you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

I've always been a big fan of Qt

https://www.qt.io/developers/

a very nice cross-platform C++ UI framework